# Kibana disable auto refresh option on dashboards

Tags: kibana

According to this page

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.x/autorefresh.html

and the last sentence

> if auto refresh is not enabled, click Refresh to manually refresh the search results.

It seems like there is a way to disable auto refresh on any dashboard somewhere.

I searched a lot but unfortunately I did not find anything on how to do this.

Reason is our clients open the dashboards, configure them to the minimum refresh rate (every 5 seconds) and leave it open all the time (even over night) which causes a constant load on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Feel your pain:

> configure them to the minimum refresh rate (every 5 seconds) and leave it open all the time (even over night) which causes a constant load on the server.

There is an option to set refreshing disabled by default:

*Stack Management* => *Advanced Settings* => *Kibana* => *Advanced Settings* => *Time filter refresh interval*

**timepicker:refreshIntervalDefaults**

```
{"value":60000,"pause":true}
```

It doesn't prevent users to alter a local browser tab setting but it prevents unnecessary refresh calls from those who unaware or forgot to close browser tab.

Setting **timepicker:refreshIntervalDefaults** in Kibana Console didn't propagate quick in my experience. Even after restarting Elastic + Kibana + refreshing browser. But next day I loaded Kibana it was applied:

- https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/21438 (Turning off refresh interval doesn't work in Kibana till you reload the browser)
- https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/35459 ( [kibana-7][auto-refresh] Auto-refresh is enabled and I can't stop it)

Comment: Disabling auto-refresh now works, just like the author described. Just don't forget to reload the page, i.e. F5.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn’t find a way to disable the option. It seems they mentioned the "Refresh every" option in that blog. Like, if that "Refresh every" option is disabled, we need to refresh it manually.

I am also searching for an option to disable that for specific Kibana users/roles.

Elasticstack 7.10 with xPack enabled.